# Generating Captions for Captioned Food Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, caption, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a college project. We're working on captioned food data set. We currently have the data set consisting of Captioned and Non Captioned, Food and food related images.

There 2 problems I have: 
1) The number of captioned images are less then uncaptioned images.
2) Some captions are just food name's while others have information regarding how the food is, how the food looks, etc.

With these problems I'm not sure how to use the uncaptioned data effectively.

I can run an integrated CNN and RNN with LSTM for captioned images. But since the uncaptioned image data set is greater than captioned how to use the data effectively.

Or should i start a clustering CNN algorithm to find similar images and then use photo id of those images with captions and give it to the clustered class. If so then consider a situation which has a cluster of two captioned images and one uncaptioned image which caption should be given to the uncaptioned image?

I've used Spacy and gotten rid of useless information in the captions.Like getting rid of prepositions and other useless information.

Number of food items
Without captions are :  57906 
With Captions : 56968 
Non Food : 85126

Any good ways to use the data set effectively?